# Could anyone help me fix this issue with TightVNC?

Tags: xfce, logs, tightvncserver

I installed TightVNC and it worked fine for the first 2 days. However, when I restarted it, it gave me these errors in the log files:

```
19/04/22 17:16:32 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
19/04/22 17:16:32 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
19/04/22 17:16:32 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
19/04/22 17:16:32 All Rights Reserved.
19/04/22 17:16:32 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
19/04/22 17:16:32 Desktop name 'X' (ubuntu:1)
19/04/22 17:16:32 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
19/04/22 17:16:32 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
xrdb: No such file or directory
xrdb: can't open file '/home/user/.Xresources'
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1(xfwm4:199773): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:16:33.821: XSync extension too old (3.0).(xfwm4:199773): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:16:33.822: The display does not support the XRender extension.(xfwm4:199773): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:16:33.822: The display does not support the XRandr extension.(xfwm4:199773): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:16:33.822: The display does not support the XRes extension.(xfwm4:199773): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:16:33.822: The display does not support the XComposite extension.(xfwm4:199773): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:16:33.822: The display does not support the XDamage extension.(xfwm4:199773): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:16:33.822: The display does not support the XFixes extension.(xfwm4:199773): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:16:33.822: The display does not support the XPresent extension.(xfwm4:199773): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:16:33.822: Compositing manager disabled.
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.846: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>Tab'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.846: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Up'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.846: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Left'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.846: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Right'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.846: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Down'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.846: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_End'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.846: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Next'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.846: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Home'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.846: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Page_Up'(xfwm4:199773): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:16:33.854: Cannot find visual format on screen 0(xfwm4:199773): GLib-CRITICAL **: 17:16:33.854: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed(xfsettingsd:199779): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: 17:16:33.890: No RANDR extension found in display :1. Display settings won't be applied.
Xlib: extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".(xfsettingsd:199779): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: 17:16:33.890: XI is not present.(xfsettingsd:199779): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: 17:16:33.890: Failed to initialize the Xkb extension.(xfsettingsd:199779): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: 17:16:33.890: Failed to initialize the Accessibility extension.
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.945: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>Tab'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.945: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Up'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.945: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Left'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.945: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Right'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.945: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Down'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.945: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_End'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.945: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Next'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.945: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Home'
xfwm4-Message: 17:16:33.945: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>KP_Page_Up'** (xiccd:199805): CRITICAL **: 17:16:34.263: RandR extension is not working on display :1.0
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused** (xfce4-power-manager:199831): WARNING **: 17:16:34.394: Failed to get name owner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.PowerManagement': no such name
** (xfce4-power-manager:199831): WARNING **: 17:16:34.394: Failed to get name owner: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.xfce.PowerManager': no such nameXlib: extension "DPMS" missing on display ":1.0".(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.401: Monitor is not DPMS capable(xfce4-power-manager:199831): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 17:16:34.439: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2614: signal 'Changed' is invalid for instance '0x5598190c4970' of type 'GDBusProxy'** (xfce4-screensaver:199809): WARNING **: 17:16:34.446: screensaver already running in this session(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.484: could not map keysym 1008ff2a to keycode
(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.484: could not map keysym 1008ffa8 to keycode
(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.484: could not map keysym 1008ffa7 to keycode
(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.484: could not map keysym 1008ff2f to keycode
(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.484: could not map keysym 1008ff02 to keycode
(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.484: could not map keysym 1008ff03 to keycode
(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.484: could not map keysym 1008ff93 to keycode
(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.484: could not map keysym 1008ff05 to keycode
(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.484: could not map keysym 1008ff06 to keycode
(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.485: No idle counter.(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.492: Unable to inhibit systemd sleep: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Permission denied** (xfce4-power-manager:199831): WARNING **: 17:16:34.492: No XRANDR extension found(xfce4-power-manager:199831): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 17:16:34.496: Failed to get keyboard max brightness level : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight” on object at path /org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight** (xfdesktop:199791): WARNING **: 17:16:34.519: Failed to set the background '/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-verticals.png': GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface “org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.AccountsService”** (wrapper-2.0:199959): WARNING **: 17:16:35.335: No XRANDR extension found(wrapper-2.0:199960): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 17:16:35.522: g_file_new_for_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed(wrapper-2.0:199960): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 17:16:35.522: g_file_monitor_file: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed(wrapper-2.0:199960): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 17:16:35.522: invalid (NULL) pointer instance(wrapper-2.0:199960): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:16:35.522: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed(wrapper-2.0:199960): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:16:35.522: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkToggleButton to a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, but the widget is already inside a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, please remove the widget from its existing container first.** (wrapper-2.0:199958): WARNING **: 17:16:35.572: Binding 'XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!(wrapper-2.0:199958): pulseaudio-plugin-WARNING **: 17:16:35.572: Could not have grabbed volume control keys. Is another volume control application (xfce4-volumed) running?** (wrapper-2.0:199958): WARNING **: 17:16:35.572: Binding 'XF86AudioPlay' failed!(wrapper-2.0:199958): pulseaudio-plugin-WARNING **: 17:16:35.572: Could not have grabbed multimedia control keys.(wrapper-2.0:199958): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:16:35.630: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PulseaudioButton)(wrapper-2.0:199960): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:16:35.642: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)(wrapper-2.0:199959): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:16:35.683: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PowerManagerButton)
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Additional information:

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish
```

Output of `uname -r`:

```
5.13.0-28-generic
```

Comment: How exactly are you starting VNC? are you allowing the server to choose the next available display, or are you specifying a display explicitly like `vncserver :1`? The error message `X server already running on display :1` suggests that an X server (either on a "real" display, or another VNC virtual server) is already running.

Comment: I've just done vncserver without anything else.
and when I try to kill it doesn't work it says

Can't find file /home/user/.vnc/ubuntu:1.pid
You'll have to kill the Xtightvnc process manually